# How to find xpath expression for this website?

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to scrape this webpage.

I have many resumes and my mission is to collect the skills for each one.
This is the link of the webpage ==> https://www.livecareer.com/resume-search/search?jt=software%20engineer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no need to use `selenium` here. U can easily do this using `BeautifulSoup`. Here is the complete code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.livecareer.com/resume-search/search?jt=software%20engineer').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')

ul = soup.find('ul',class_ = 'resume-list list-unstyled')

li_items = ul.find_all('li')[1:]

links = []

for li in li_items:
    links.append('https://www.livecareer.com/'+li.a['href'])

skills = []

for link in links:
    
    r = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div',class_ = 'field singlecolumn')
    skills.append(div.text)

print(skills)
```

Output:

```
['agile, AutoCAD, C++, CAD, Oral, data entry, database, Engineer in Training, EIT, Engineering analysis, XML, functional, GUI, HTML, JavaScript, Team leadership, Lockheed Martin, macros, Manufacturing processes, MATLAB, mechanical, meetings, Excel, Organizational skills, presentations, Process improvement, program management, programming, Project planning, Python, research, scrum, Six Sigma, Software development, Solidworks, SQL, switches, telemetry, video, Web design, website, Written communication', "Senior Outreach at Senior Center\xa0Planned and organized a joint celebration of the Chinese New Year with the collaboration of the Westborough Public Schools. \xa0Promoted cultural awareness and broke the language barrier of different races of backgrounds.Volunteer at ChurchIdentified problems and implemented a process to eliminate a data-entry camp registration process by 100% by building new online Registration Forms for registration and the student's cultural classes arrangement.Designed posters, flyers and presentation slides with graphics and photos for the different organizational events with Microsoft Word and PowerPointDeveloped a structural documentation on publishing an annual report with detailed steps and instructions on the process that are easy to follow and quickly learn by others. \xa0Implemented a 30th Anniversary Special Edition project in a commercial quality of work with excellent time management skills to meet the deadline.Cayenne SoftwareExperienced team spirit in effort of reducing the workload of bugs fixes on the software product.\u200bAllmerica Financial CompanyProvided a sole support to the Hanover 1099 system with strong commitment and responsibility. Fined tuned the system resulting in cost savings for the Allmerica Financial Company. Winner of the Gold Crown Customer Recognition award.", 'Motivated Software Engineer seeking employment as part of a dynamic software development team. Fluent in C,C++,JAVA and python.', 'Developed peer-to-peer secure file transfer system in JAVA.This involved the application of symmetric\r\n     and asymmetric key cryptography algorithms, and JAVA concepts like multi-threading, socket\r\n     programming, etc.Implemented a system to query XML in JAVA.The query language was a subset of XPath\r\n    Modeled a project "Personal Health Management System" using UML and implemented it in Visual C#.The code was tested using NUnit.Object oriented software development process was used for this\r\n     project\r\n    Developed a \'license plate game\' in C on LINUX o/s using client/server architecture.This required the\r\n     application of distributed programming concepts like Sockets, RPC, multi-threading, etc.RESEARCH PAPER:\r\n    XMorph: A Shape-Polymorphic, Domain-Specific XML Data Transformation Language,\r\n     International Conference on Data Engineering (ICDE 2010), IEEE CS, Los Angeles, USA, March 2010.', 'Performance evaluation of In-Kernel System Call Implemented and evaluated In-kernel system call using dynamic loadable kernel module on x_86_64 architecture.Re-Development free approach to migrate Java applications to cloud at College of Engineering, Pune Implemented file access sub-system of a WebJDK which leverages the File-System API provided by HTML5.This allows the use of standard Java APIs for accessing client files.2016 2013.', 'Accomplished Computer Technician with a rapidly increasing range of industry experience looking to bring strong instincts and a proven record of procedural compliance, process management and strong operational skills to a rapidly growing company. ', 'Seeking a fulltime position as a Developer / Systems Admin / DBA for a company needing a hard working, \r\ntaskoriented person with an indepth understanding of software development and database tuning.', '3 Years of experience in Information Technology with emphasis on Design, Development and End to End Implementation of Consulting based solutions with expertise on working with Object Orient Analysis and Design using Java/J2EE Technologies viz. JSP/Servlets/EJB,JDBC, Web services , Web sockets, Spring Frameworks, Spring-boot, Angular, JQuery, XML/XSLT, JSON, Integration Developer Service Component Architecture & Service Data Objects, Rational Application Developer, Test Driven Development using JUnit, Jenkins, GIT, Cloud Foundry,  Eclipse/Intelij IDE, UNIX, Gradle Scripts, DB2/Oracle/MySQL Databases.', '.NET 3.5, .NET, ASP .NET 3.5, ASP.NET 2.0, ASP.NET 3.5, AJAX, ASM, Banking, Basic, Business Objects, c, CSS, CSS 2, customer satisfaction, data analysis, Database, delivery, EBusiness, editor, Electronics, HP, HTML 4, HTML, IDE, IIS 7.0, ITIL, JavaScript, C#, C# 3.0, Windows, windows applications, 2000, 3.1, Windows 98, Enterprise, Oct, Operating systems, Oracle 9, Oracle database, PL/SQL, personnel, programming, recording, reporting, sales, Servers, Service Level Agreement, SLA, Visual SourceSafe, Visual  SourceSafe, SQL, SQL Server, technical support, TOAD, UNIX, vi, Microsoft Visual Studio, Visual studio, Windows server', 'Represent Stanford  Ballroom Dance team in various competitions in the Bay area.\r\n*Represented University of Maryland in Ballroom dance competitions in UMD, UPenn, MIT, Columbia University & Ohio \r\n*Have a keen interest in photography, especially of dancers in motion.']
```

U can also create a beautiful `DataFrame` using this (for better readability) by adding these lines to ur code:

```
dictionary = {'Links':links,
              'Skills':skills}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                                                                           
                Skills                                                   Links
0  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  agile, AutoCAD, C++, CAD, Oral, data entry, da...
1  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Senior Outreach at Senior Center Planned and o...
2  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Motivated Software Engineer seeking employment...
3  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Developed peer-to-peer secure file transfer sy...
4  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Performance evaluation of In-Kernel System Cal...
5  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Accomplished Computer Technician with a rapidl...
6  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Seeking a fulltime position as a Developer / S...
7  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  3 Years of experience in Information Technolog...
8  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  .NET 3.5, .NET, ASP .NET 3.5, ASP.NET 2.0, ASP...
9  https://www.livecareer.com//resume-search/r/so...  Represent Stanford  Ballroom Dance team in var...
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: thank it is really helpful but I need XPath because I'm using scrapy and I'm not familiar with beautifulsoup

Comment: But if u definitely wanna use scrapy, then u have to follow Steven Hardy's answer.

Comment: But ```BeautifulSoup``` is the best library for scraping information from websites. So decide which one u wanna use.

Answer (score 1):

Going to throw this out there.....

As mentioned, used chrome
right click the element you want
click inspect
hit ctrl + f to bring up the search window

Then write your xpath so it returns one (and only one) page object.

ex:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'my text')] 
//div[@id='myDivID']
```

create the xpath for the item. Never Ever Ever Use "Copy Xpath" option. You will get paths like the below which is the most brittle xpath you can write.

```
//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/aside[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a
```

If you are not familiar with writing xpath, go here and read up https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

The one issue you have here is that the text is within a div tag and really should be in a span. You can try the below:

```
//div[@class='field singlecolumn']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Developer Tools of your browser to find the XPath of any html element. The below example is for Chrome, however the steps will be very similar for other browsers:

1. Right click on the item on the page you want to know the XPath for.
2. Click "Inspect". This will open the Dev Tools, with the element in question highlighted.
3. If the element you are after is not the one highlighted, navigate around in the interactive html displayed. Usually as you hover an element the matching item is highlighted in the main page.
4. Right click on the html element in the navigator.
5. Select 'Copy -> Copy XPath'.

The main issue you might encounter when scraping these pages, is that the your target may not be in the same location each time. If these are documents created by users, then they may have a different layout each time, so the XPath might not match the same section on each page. If that is the case, you may need to do a more complicated approach (jQuery, Selenium, Cypress, etc all have tools for searching by text content, navigating between parent/child elements etc.)

Comment: thank it is really helpful but I need XPath because I'm using scrapy and I'm not familiar with beautifulsoup can you help please

Comment: It was @Sushil 's answer that mentioned beautifulsoup. You'll find in my answer exactly what your looking for, the instructions on how to work out the XPath of any element on a page...